# C# UDP sockets: sending/receiveing from one specified port to another specified port

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient

I have an embedded system, and I want to send and receive information on it using UDP on C#. And I can't make my program to receive completely valid UDP packet.

Embedded system waits for a UDP packet to port 57301, sent from port 57301 (not the arbitrary one!) and then answers to port 57311 from port 57311. Wireshark shows me completely valid packets from computer to embedded system and from embedded system to computer, but C# program doesn't want to see it.

```
    // Button handler, I press it to send message
    private void SendUDP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Send();

    }

    // Button handler, I press it before sending anything just to start receiver
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartReceive();
    }

    // Sending completely as planned
    void Send()
    {
        UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(57301);
        byte[] message = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Message.Text);

        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.14"), 57301);
        udp.Send(message, message.Length, ep);
        udp.Close();
    }

    void StartReceive()
    {
        ThreadStart tstart = new ThreadStart(Receive);
        workReceive = new Thread(tstart);
        workReceive.Start();
    }


    bool stopReceive = false;
    Thread workReceive = null;
    UdpClient udp = null;

    void Receive()
    {
        ShowMessage("Receive started");
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 57311);
            udp = new UdpClient(ep);

            while (true)
            {
                IPEndPoint remote = null;
                byte[] message = udp.Receive(ref remote);   // <--- NEVER RECEIVE ANYTHING!
                ShowMessage("Received!");

                if (stopReceive == true) break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ShowMessage("Exception!");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (udp != null) udp.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions where the problem is?

UPD: The problem were in embedded system: wrong UDP checksum calculation routine - don't know why I thought that it should be the same as ip4 routine.